# LibGdx build.gradle not loading

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I used the libGDX project setup tool to generate a new project. The instructions say that I should reimport all Gradle projects but when I do, I get these errors:
[image]

Btw, I am using JDK 17.03 and I'm following these instructions: https://libgdx.com/wiki/start/import-and-running. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1**

Running `.\gradlew build` on the command line shows the root cause:

```
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.11.0.
     Required by:
         project :core
      > Could not resolve com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.11.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx/1.11.0/gdx-1.11.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx/1.11.0/gdx-1.11.0.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Now I understand that it is related to the network security on my work laptop.

Comment: Gradle 8 might be a problem. The [recommended gradle version](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-setup/res/com/badlogic/gdx/setup/resources/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L3) for LibGdx 1.11 is Gradle 7.3.3. See the [updating guide](https://libgdx.com/wiki/articles/updating-libgdx#gradle-wrapper).